# Is the Hypothalamus part of the Central Nervous System or Endocrine System

Tags: neuroscience

Sorry for a certainly naive question. 
Some references (for example https://faculty.washington.edu/chudler/nsdivide.html) seem to to indicate that the hypothalamus is part of the Central Nervous System. Others (for example http://kidshealth.org/teen/your_body/body_basics/endocrine.html) place it in the Endrocrine System. I would have said it is part of both, but then I read the two systems are distinct. Could anyone explain me to which one it belongs and why?

Thanks,

Gilles

Comment: CNS refers to the brain and spinal cord. Its a very general term. Hypothalamus is part of the CNS but its unique in a sense that it secretes many chemicals into the bloodstream like glands! so they are both correct!

Comment: If the above comment has answered your question, please let me know so I can post it as an answer so that the question does not remain unanswered.

Comment: Hi Bez, I was just waiting a little to see if anyone else would argue with what you said. Please post it as an answer as it is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_nervous_system) refers to the brain and spinal cord. Its a very general term. Hypothalamus is part of the [CNS structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_nervous_system#Structure) but its unique in a sense that it secretes many chemicals into the bloodstream like glands hence part of the [endocrine system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endocrine_system)! so they are both correct!

Comment: Can you add some references to your answer? Actually it is more a comment.

Comment: @Chris Apologies for failing to reference. Hope the response references are satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the CNS and does *not* secrete hormones into the bloodstream. Instead, it delivers input to the pituitary gland, which is an endocrine organ and secretes hormones into the bloodstream. Please refer to http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothalamus and specifically the section "Neural Connections". Otherwise, any basic neuroscience or endocrinology textbook covers this under hypothalamic-pituitary axis or the likes. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you add some references to your answer? Actually it is more a comment.

Comment: I have added some suggestions Gilles. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ps. Questions like these are not naive and opportunity for interesting discussions!